# Is there any limit on the number of displayed jobs on pipeline's details page? (gitlab)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

It was experimentally found that not all jobs are displayed on Gitlab pipeline's page. But I can't find any mention of this in the documentation. Only 100 "rows" are shown.

Answer (score 0):

This should be part of [GitLab API pagination](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#pagination)

> `per_page`    Number of items to list per page (default: 20, max: 100)

If the GitLab pipeline page uses its own API, it would display up to 100 row par page.

Comment: So it is not possible to display all jobs on pipeline's web page, am i correct?

Comment: @Sergey Yes, it is not possible.